# Problem with a widget not showing when using IconButton

Tags: flutter

I am facing a problem that my PopupMenuButton not showing when I click on, I tried many solutions but without success.
I am also searched in google but with not results.
I am afraid I am facing a bug.

Here is my code

```
enum MyMenuEntries { edit, delete }

                                  IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                                      onPressed: () =>
                                          PopupMenuButton<MyMenuEntries>(
                                            onSelected:
                                                (MyMenuEntries entry) {},
                                            itemBuilder:
                                                (BuildContext context) => [
                                              PopupMenuItem<MyMenuEntries>(
                                                value: MyMenuEntries.edit,
                                                child: ListTile(
                                                    leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                                    title: Text("Edit")),
                                              ),
                                              PopupMenuItem<MyMenuEntries>(
                                                value: MyMenuEntries.delete,
                                                child: ListTile(
                                                    leading: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                                    title: Text("Delete")),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ))
```

Please any answer could help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an `IconButton`, you can use the [PopUpMenuButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html) as is and supply the icon to its `icon` property. It will automatically show the `PopUpMenuButton` items.

So you should remove the `IconButton` and your code will be:

```
PopupMenuButton<MyMenuEntries>(
    onSelected:
    (MyMenuEntries entry) {},
    itemBuilder:
    (BuildContext context) => [
        PopupMenuItem<MyMenuEntries>(
            value: MyMenuEntries.edit,
            child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
            title: Text("Edit")),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem<MyMenuEntries>(
            value: MyMenuEntries.delete,
            child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.delete),
            title: Text("Delete")),
        ),
    ], 
    icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),                                         
)
```